# MutableMap<Key, Boolean> returns nullable Boolean? for value access with key

Tags: kotlin

I created a map hardmapping values to `false`
But when I want to access it, I get offered a nullable boolean. How can I avoid it besides my suggestion down below?

```
object Keyboard{
    val keys = Key.values().associate { it to false }.toMutableMap()
    fun pressButtonForEvent(event : KeyEvent){
        keys[event.key] = true
    }

    fun isPressed(key : Key) : Boolean {
        return keys[key]
    }

}
```

### Suggestion to solve it (but I dont like it)

```
fun isPressed(key : Key) : Boolean {
    return if (keys.containsKey(key)){
        keys[key]!!
    } else false
}
```

Comment: `return keys[key] ?: false`? `return keys.getOrDefault(key, false)`?

Comment: Yep but why does it deliver a nullable Boolean in the first place when I hardmapped it to false

Comment: Because if you put two keys in the map, there are still an infinity of other keys that you could pass to map.get(), and that wouldn't be in the map, so the map can't possibly return a non-null value for this infinity of absent keys. This is documented: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get.html: *Returns the value corresponding to the given key, or null if such a key is not present in the map.*

Comment: In short, map.get always returns nullable regardless of whether the values are nullable. You can use getOrDefault or getOrElse to avoid nullables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unsure whether others can put keys into your map, use [`getOrElse`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-else.html) or  [`getOrDefault`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-default.html) to access the values:

```
keys.getOrElse(key) { false }
keys.getOrDefault(key, false)
```

Alternatively initialize your map using a [`withDefault`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-default.html)-wrapper:, e.g.:

```
keys = mutableMapOf<Key, Boolean>().withDefault { false } // in the end you initialize every key with false
```

Accessing the value can then be achieved via [`getValue`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html):

```
keys.getValue(key)
```

If you use `getValue` without `withDefault` you will get an exception if there is no value for the given key. Using it with a proper `withDefault` setup it will always give you the default value if there is no such key in the map.

Last but not least: if you have full control over that map and no one will ever put anything else into it, a `keys[key]!!` might also be ok... In every other case `keys.getValue(key)` is probably better as the exception message clearly states which key is missing whereas with `!!` you just get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: withDefault wrapper is awesome